# Get attributes of simple products which consist in configurable product

Tags: magento-1.6

How i can get attributes of simple products which consist in configurable product ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this is not what you are asking, but you can start with [`Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Configurable::getUsedProductAttributes()`](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.6/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Type/Configurable.php#L223):

```
public function getUsedProductAttributes($product = null)
{
    if (!$this->getProduct($product)->hasData($this->_usedProductAttributes)) {
        $usedProductAttributes = array();
        $usedAttributes        = array();
        foreach ($this->getConfigurableAttributes($product) as $attribute) {
            if (!is_null($attribute->getProductAttribute())) {
                $id = $attribute->getProductAttribute()->getId();
                $usedProductAttributes[$id] = $attribute->getProductAttribute();
                $usedAttributes[$id]        = $attribute;
            }
        }
        $this->getProduct($product)->setData($this->_usedAttributes, $usedAttributes);
        $this->getProduct($product)->setData($this->_usedProductAttributes, $usedProductAttributes);
    }
    return $this->getProduct($product)->getData($this->_usedProductAttributes);
}
```